# How do Ajax calls fit in with a MVC structure

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller

I'm using MySQL/PHP/Jquery and a custom `MVC` structure because my app is fairly small. My question is (*and this could be in any language*): When using a `MVC` programming structure where do the files you hit via ajax go?

For example I use long polling to show the status (progress bar) of background processing. In my `non-MVC` version of this tool I just have a php file that is only hit by the ajax call, it makes an object and calls a method to return the percentage done. Ajax returns my number and updates a progress bar.

How does this ajax loading fit into a `MVC` structure?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC is just a pattern. JavaScript code itself can implement this pattern, so I don't think of it as fitting into some other portion of your server side framework's pattern. Check out [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) for a good example of using MVC in JavaScript code.

You can model your JavaScript code off of similar concepts that you model your server side code with. The JavaScript code itself will get served up through the view of your server side application, but unless you're only adding eye candy with JavaScript code (which you're not) then the JavaScript code is really its own entity and doesn't necessarily fit into your server side MVC paradigm.

Try to separate the JavaScript code from anything server side. Just consider it an 'add on' that, if disabled in the browser, won't break your application from running. I just add some niceties to allow for better interaction, etc. How you actually model the JavaScript code is up to you, (but I do highly recommend Backbone)

One could also do a Rich frontend in javascript backed only by a data source. In this case, once again, javascript will be responsible for maintaining models, views and controllers.

Domain model generally just refers to the business logic of your application. The brains so to speak of what should actually happen in your app. It's kind of an abstract concept encapsulating all the business logic of an app.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes Ive used backbone before on a really large project and I was debating it for this situation. I was afraid I was reaching for a huge tool for a little problem so I asked :)

Comment: Yes, I guess I was expecting to find the "Correct Way" to structure it (if only the file structure). But I already keep all of the ajax hit .php files separate, so if I name them with the controllers it will all fit together quite nicely. Plus if I get backbone running it will be more tied into the whole structure.

Answer (score 1):

im using codeigniter, im using an dedicated controller for ajax and checking $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] to determine if its an ajax request.
you can use same approach, and you can keep all of your structure(use your models in ajax controller etc...)